# FullCalendar scrollTime method is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using **FullCalendar v5**

```js
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  eventClick: function (info) {
    $('.popover').popover('hide')
    $('a.popover-event' + info.event.id).popover('show')
  },

  eventResize: function (info) {
    console.log(info);
  },
  eventDidMount: function (event) {
    $(event.el).attr('data-trigger', 'focus')
    $(event.el).attr('tabindex', -1)
  },

  timeZone: 'local',
  slotEventOverlap: false,
  eventColor: '#c1c1c1',
  editable: false,
  schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
  initialView: 'resourceTimeGridTwoDay1',
  nowIndicator: true,
  initialDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
  slotMaxTime: '18:00:00',
  selectable: true,
  locales: 'ru',
  duration: { days: 1 },
  scrollTime: moment().format("HH:mm:ss"),


});
```

I want to load calendar view from current timeline (or from `now indicator`), I read in documentation about `ScrollTime` but it's not working

---

`resourceTimeGridTwoDay1` configuration

```js
views: {
    resourceTimeGridTwoDay1: {
      type: 'resourceTimeGrid',
      buttonText: '1 day',
    },
  }
```

---

**Screenshot** of my FullCalendar

[image]

Comment: `initialView: 'resourceTimeGridTwoDay1'` ...is this a custom view you defined? If so please show us the configuration of it.

Comment: @adyson, Thank you for responding, I added configuration for `resourceTimeGridTwoDay1`

Comment: From what I can tell from a brief experiment, it only seems to take effect when there's a height restriction on the calendar - e.g. https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/QWKwXRd . Otherwise, if the calendar content has no scroll bars, there's nowhere for it to scroll! It's not clear if your calendar has such a restriction or not.

Comment: @ADyson, I updated the post, look at the screenshot.

Comment: @ADyson, I also added   `contentHeight` to the options, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
The problem was that I rerender the calendar multiple times and change views after some AJAX calls.
Problem solved by calling method `scrollToTime()` after rerendering calendar.

Thank you