Fullcalendar scrollToTime not working. Page remains unmoved even after using setTimeOut
I am trying to display Fullcalendar in "timeGridDay" and datesSet or loading or eventsSet methods. I am making use of scrollToTime('07:00:00') method but its not working. The page remains unmoved. Please help me.
this.calendarOptions = {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, multiMonthPlugin],
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
    nowIndicator: true,
    initialView: 'timeGridDay',
    editable: true,
    views: {
        timeGridDay: {
            titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit'
        },
        dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
        slotLabelFormat: slotLabelFormat,
        allDaySlot: true,
        allDayText: 'All Day',
        eventDrop: this.handleEventDrop.bind(this),
        eventResize: this.handleEventDrop.bind(this),
        dayMaxEvents: maxDisplay,
        eventsSet: () => { 
            this.fullcalendar?.getApi().scrollToTime("07:00:00");
        }
    } 
}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059614/fullcalendar-scrolltime-method-is-not-working#comment115038190_65059614

@ADyson I have the calendar setup good and I can make gotoDate function too. Having error only with scrollToTime method. Calendar also have scrolls and can scroll manually.
